# How do you search by Date using when it is stored as a String?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I've got a legacy database that stores dates both as plain text strings and actual dates. The more relevant/important date is stored as a string.

Using GORM against the Strings is fairly straightforward.

The difficulty I have is that I need to search by date and that date is stored as a string in two different formats i.e. "11/28/2014" and "11/28/2014 12:00:00 AM"

Comment: 1) Can the database column be corrected (or minimally, can the values therein be normalized)? 2) Can a computed column be added? 3) Can a [computed/materialized] view be added? 4) What *type* of search operation is required - a _specific_ Date or a _range_ of Dates? 5) What is the worst-case performance bounds/complexity allowed for the search (eg. how many rows are there, and what multiplicity is involved)?

Comment: is this database using SQL?

Comment: 1) It cannot be corrected. 2) A computed column will probably be the fastest approach as this is a view. 3) It is a view I'm searching against. 4) A range of dates as well as specific dates. 4) Prior to a recently annoucned data limitation we were in the millions of rows range.

Answer (score 0):

You are not going to be able to do this without a solution specific to your database and that solution would depend on what database you are using.  Wanting to do this is evidence that your database is not designed to satisfy your requirement.  If you have to visit every single record in a table and do a string conversion so you can filter based on the result of that conversion, that isn't going to scale.  If you have a small database and aren't concerned about the performance hit, it might be do-able depending on your database but there isn't going to be a good general solution for this.

Comment: I agree with everything you said Jeff and I've previously presented  this to my company but they are against changing/can't change. The database was not designed by me nor is it normalized or representational of any sort of state or object i.e. 5 columns are named similarity to column1, column2, etc and logic is put in the database to determine which to use when. This database is "small" by comparison and doing this limits the data set even more. If it helps the database is Oracle 11g.

Comment: If you are ok with Oracle specific stuff then just write a stored procedure that does what you want and move on.  GORM doesn't need to be involved in that.

Answer (score 0):

You could also search .withCriteria { .. } and spesify both formats within an OR statement, in SQL something like this:

```
WHERE (date = '2014/01/01' OR date = '2014/01/01 12:00:00 AM')
AND something_else = "other-thing"
```

However the underlying problem is still there like stated in the replies earlier.

Comment: Thanks boubbin but I don't see how this would allow for a less than or greater than comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bring all your dates to the same data type. 
That way is easier to compare and manipulate them.
Why not try converting your string values to Date values?
Open a `grails console` in your project directory and try this:

```
String myDate1 = "11/28/2014"
def newDate1 = new Date().parse("M/d/yyyy", myDate1)
println "newDate1 = ${newDate1}"
println "newDate1 plus one day = ${newDate1 + 1}"

String myDate2 = "11/28/2014 12:00:00 AM"
def newDate2 = new Date().parse("M/d/yyyy H:m:s a", myDate2)
println "newDate2 = ${newDate2}"
println "newDate2 plus one day = ${newDate1 + 1}"
```

You should get this output:

```
newDate1 = Fri Nov 28 00:00:00 PST 2014
newDate1 plus one day = Sat Nov 29 00:00:00 PST 2014
newDate2 = Fri Nov 28 12:00:00 PST 2014
newDate2 plus one day = Sat Nov 29 00:00:00 PST 2014
```

And as you said this is not a very large database so you will have to filter your searches in a loaded array. But once having your values as Date you could compare "greater than" and "less than" values.